# Sscanf - read all numbers from a file - C

Tags: c, scanf

I would like to read all numbers from `.txt` file using `sscanf`. In the main function, I opened the `.txt` file with `fopen( name.txt, "r")`.
The following code is only reading first strings and first numbers, but I can't iterate it:

```c
    int test(FILE *file){
    int l = 0;
    char buffer[256];
    char *poi = NULL;
    while(fgets(buffer, 256, file) != NULL){
        poi = buffer;
        for(;*poi != '\n'; poi++){
            sscanf(buffer, "%[^0-9]%d", zahl[l].buf, &zahl[l].number);
            l++;
        }
    }
```

For instance:

In the `.txt` file is following text:

```
In 2019 we had 200 accidents
In 2020 we had 199 accidents
```

The code above would only read 2019 and 2020, but not 200 or 199 - how can I tell `sscanf` to keep scanning until new line `'\n'` appears?

Comment: With `"abc123xyz\n"`, `"abc123\n"`, `"123xyz\n"`, `"123\n"`, `"abc\n"`, `"\n"`, what should go into `zahl[l].buf, &zahl[l].number`?

Comment: In the .txt file you will find a random text, which contains numbers and strings. See example above. The task is to read all numbers of the .txt file and place strings into zahl[l].buf and numbes into &zahl[l].number. @user786653 told already a good way to do it, however, it doesn't read numbers at the beginning of a line, as sscanf doesn't find a string due to %[^0-9].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You're always scanning from the start of `buffer`, you need to scan from `poi` (point of interest?)
- You need to advance `poi` by the number of characters read
- A newline character might not be present in `buffer`

For the second point you can use `%n` to get the number of characters read so far.

With this you end with a loop like:

```
    while (*poi) {
        int nc;
        if (2 == sscanf(poi, "%[^0-9]%d%n", zahl[l].buf, &zahl[l].number, &nc))
            poi += nc;
        else
            break;
        l++;
    }
```

Comment: Alright thanks, it is doing, what it has to be except reading the numbers at the beginning of a new line. So if a line would start with a number for example 2019 text, it wouldn't read the number due to %[^0-9] in the sscanf function . I already tried to code like %[^0-9]* or %*[^0-9] - both didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: You probably need a more complex parsing function depending on what you need to match. If you don't need the text between numbers you could use a loop with `whle (*poi && !isdigit(*poi))` to skip non-characters before grabbing the number. But you might be better off opening another question.